# Python set update with iterable

Tags: python, set, iterable

What I have at hand is a text file of decent size (~ 23MB). I am reading the file line by line and extracting a few words from each line based on some external criteria. For the sake of this example, let's say each line contains at least half a dozen tab-separated values and I am picking up all except the first and the last.

I want to output the set of *unique* words obtained this way, so obviously I want to store the extracted words in a `set`. Also, since `set.update(other)` is significantly faster than looping through `other` and adding one word at a time with `set.add(elem)`, I tried doing this:

```
all_words = set()
with open(my_tsv_file) as tsv_file:
    for line in tsv_file:
        wordlist = based_on_some_criteria(line)    # this is a list, not a set
        all_words.update(wordlist)
```

And this works fine. But when I replaced `all_words.update(wordlist)` with `all_words |= wordlist`, I got the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |=: 'set' and 'list'
```

From the documentation, I understand that `update` and `|=` are equivalent. Further, since `|=` is supposed to accept any iterable, I also confirmed by doing this:

```
import collections
isinstance(wordlist, collections.Iterable)        # returns True
```

Why is the first approach using `set.update` working, but not the second one using `|=`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> From the documentation, I understand that update and |= are equivalent. Further, since |= is supposed to accept any iterable...

From the documentation:

> Note, the non-operator versions of the `update()`, `intersection_update()`, `difference_update()`, and `symmetric_difference_update()` methods will accept any iterable as an argument.

The documentation does not seem to agree with your understanding.

Comment: Ah! Completely misunderstood the documentation on my first reading.

Answer (score 5):

`set` methods such as `update` accept arbitrary iterables, while `set` operators such as `|` and `|=` require sets.

Quoting [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

> Note, the non-operator versions of `union()`, `intersection()`,
>   `difference()`, and `symmetric_difference()`, `issubset()`, and `issuperset()`
>   methods will accept any iterable as an argument. In contrast, their
>   operator based counterparts require their arguments to be sets. This
>   precludes error-prone constructions like `set('abc') & 'cbs'` in favor
>   of the more readable `set('abc').intersection('cbs')`.

Comment: And a little further on the docs say `Note, the non-operator versions of the update(), intersection_update(), difference_update(), and symmetric_difference_update() methods will accept any iterable as an argument.`

Comment: @PM2Ring That's the passage I quoted in the answer. :)

Comment: Not quite. The passage you quoted doesn't mention the `update` family of methods; but that passage does have some useful info that is omitted in the passage Ignacio and I quoted (which is why I gave you an up-vote).

Comment: @PM2Ring Indeed, you're right. The passages are so similar that it is only by accident that I quoted the one with the additional info. Thanks for the upvote.